# How to show two numbers in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please tell me how to show number all time.

Given : **LastNumber**

```
  when **previous** button click .
    Result: 10 11 
    Result: 9 10 
    Result: 8 9
```

if user click **next** button

```
Result: 9 10 
  Result: 10 11
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LyXLD/3/

```
function printdown(count) {
    $("#pre").html('')
    $("#pre").html($("#curr").html());
    $("#curr").html('')
    $("#curr").html(count);
    // $("#pre").html(count);


}

$("#next").click(function () {
    if (++file_show_counter <= lastestCountValue) {
        printdown(file_show_counter);

    } else {
        file_show_counter--;

    }
});
```

Comment: It is not necessary to set the inner HTML to blank before adding a different value.

Comment: ok..but my result not getting

Comment: u can do this.define an array before your function get called.when you call your function, add the number in array and after that retrieve the values.

Answer (score 1):

> i have 11 pages.and i have to show 2 pages at one time.i just know how
> many pages i have mean (11). when i go up it show 9 and 10 page.then 8
> and 9 page

## Update

Well now that OP has actually stated this requirement, here's an updated solution.
Prev button stops working when it gets down to 1, and the next button stops working when it reaches the page count.

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/RkAzV/)

```
var pageCount = 11;
$("#previous").on("click", function () {
    $pre = $("#pre");
    $curr = $("#curr");
    $count = +$pre.text();
    if ($count > 1) {
        $pre.text($count - 1);
        $curr.text($count);
    }
});
$("#next").on("click", function () {
    $pre = $("#pre");
    $curr = $("#curr");
    $count = +$curr.text();
    if ($count < pageCount) {
        $pre.text($count);
        $curr.text($count + 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: OP doesn't want more than 11

Comment: When did he say that?

Comment: He is insisting on LastNumber and in his jsfiddle, he is checking if it is less than ll.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#previos').click(function () {
        var prevVal = parseInt($('#pre').html());
        var curVal = parseInt($('#curr').html());
        $('#pre').text(prevVal - 1);
        $('#curr').text(curVal - 1);
    });
    $('#next').click(function () {
        var prevVal = parseInt($('#pre').html());
        var curVal = parseInt($('#curr').html());
        if (curVal < 11) {
            $('#pre').text(prevVal + 1);
            $('#curr').text(curVal + 1);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo:<kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/LyXLD/5/</kbd>

Comment: actually I need come change only in my js

Comment: @user2648752 why's that?

Comment: Because Actually I need some concept .which is used in my real question

Comment: I am relating my real probem to this problem

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look.  Is that what you are looking for?

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/E3Ucz/)

```
var lastestCountValue = 11,
    file_show_counter = lastestCountValue - 1;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#previos").click(function () {
        if (file_show_counter > 1) {
            print(--file_show_counter, file_show_counter + 1);
        }
    });

    $("#next").click(function () {
        if (file_show_counter < lastestCountValue - 1) {
            print(++file_show_counter, file_show_counter + 1);
        }
    });
});

function print(pre, cur) {
    $("#pre").html(pre);
    $("#curr").html(cur);
}
```

Comment: @AmitJoki I think vlad has great answer.I will tell you the problem

Comment: i have 11 pages.and i have to show 2 pages at one time.i just know how  many pages i have mean (11). when i go up it show 9 and 10 page.then 8 and 9 page

Answer (score 0):

I just write new code please check it on http://jsfiddle.net/shantanubhaware/LyXLD/10/
working code

```
var lastval = $('#curr').text();
var preval = $('#pre').text();
var i = 0;
$('#previos').click(function () {
    var lastval = $('#curr').text();
    var preval = $('#pre').text();
    previous();
});

$('#next').click(function () {
    var lastval = $('#curr').text();
    var preval = $('#pre').text();
    next();
});

function previous() {

    if (preval >= 1) {
        --lastval;
        --preval;
        $('#curr').text(lastval);
        $('#pre').text(preval);
    }
}
```